# IntelliJ - Tab indentation in Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, indentation, code-formatting

I want to use tabs for indentation in my Javascript files. I changed the configuration as usual, but the preview doesn't seem to take my modification in account. Neither in the acutal files.

What is surprising is that the "Spaces" subtab is formatting the code the right way, but it's is the only place where it works. (See screenshots below)

Did anyone have the same issue ?

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1

[image: Config page (borken preview)]

[image: Spaces subtab (working preview)]

Comment: Did you actually change the files? The setting just applies to *new* indentation, you'd have to reformat existing files in order to apply it retrospectively.

Comment: Yes, I did change the files. Actually, when I press I add a new line or try to reformat a javascript file, the indentation is converted to spaces even when I check the "Use tab character" as shown on the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look a editorconfig.org .
You will need a .editorconfig file at the root of your project. It's a markup file that works accros multiple IDE's to set some common configuration like indentation and trailing spaces. Here is an example.

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.js]
indent_size = 2
```

Comment: That was it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Is this an official solution btw? Seems odd to rely on 3rd party. It's editorconfig.org

Answer (score 3):

[From Intellij Idea 14 onwards](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/intellij-idea-14-will-detect-code-styles-on-the-fly/), IDE by default detects existing indentation styles in existing files and uses them instead of your settings. You can Turn this feature off in the prefferences:

> Prefferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Detect and use existing file indents for editing

[image]

If turning off this feature does not help, make sure your project does not have [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) file, which defines indentation styles as well.

Comment: Already tried that, not working either. And It does not explain why the preview in the config in not formatted correctly...